# Form_open duplicate my $_SERVER in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I use the last version of codeigniter with the changes to hide the index.php in the url.

This is my config.php :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'mediamax.toto.local/front/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

and this is my .htaccess at the root of my folder :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

I call my form like this in my view :

```
echo form_open('index');
```

index is my method from my controller front and this is the url which is display in my browser when I submit the form : http://mediamax.toto.local/mediamax.toto.local/front/index

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$config['base_url'] = 'mediamax.toto.local/front/';
```

To:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://mediamax.toto.local/front/';
```

Hope this helps!